# How to display a div when the user scroll to a fixed amount in a page?

Tags: jquery

I've seen this kind of tutorial before but can't seem to find it again.

How to display a div when the user scroll the page down to a fixed amount? Like in Tutorial9 [Here](http://www.tutorial9.net/photoshop/fuzzfurry-text-effect-works-great-as-grass/) when you scroll to the bottom of the article a "You might also like" div appears.

Any tutorials that explain this would be really great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the tutorial of [End of Page Slide Out Box with jQuery](http://bit.ly/dB9q18)

See it [in action here](http://bit.ly/bI5huH)